# Image Color Picker - HTML5 Canvas Security Errors?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, same-origin-policy

I'm attempting to use this thing with cross-domain images: http://www.script-tutorials.com/demos/158/index.html

But Same Origin Policy prevents me from using that http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy

Errors thrown:
[image]

Is there any way to use Image Color Picker with external images?

Comment: Why don't you just download the images to your server and use those?

Comment: Because I don't want to host them on this server - it's WPMU installation where 100 users have to share 1 image. It doesn't make sense to make 100 copies of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To enable CORS (Cross-Origin Resource Sharing) for your images pass the HTTP header with the image response:

Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *

If you cannot change that on the image server than copy that image to one of your servers.

You can also use JSONP if it is supported by the server.

Comment: That's a good solution but I decided to make PHP script download external images :) Both seem to be alright.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [this plugin](http://www.maxnov.com/getimagedata/). It's much of a hack, but that's what you expect when doing something that standards don't approve.

Comment: I've seen this just a few minutes ago but demo doesn't work in Firefox nor Chrome for me :)

Comment: @Paul Which country are you currently in, if I may ask? :)

Comment: Poland, Europe - it says 503 Service Unavailable, so maybe it's disabled for this region. I think I'll have to pass Canvas element in such event and use some other solution instead - I've seen Javascript picker - it worked but it was really slow.

Comment: @Paul Apparently that application is over its `quota`. So yes, you'll have to use another solution indeed.